# Convert base64string to downloadable file using javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

I want to download the file while clicking on the link.

```
<a href="javascript:download(375,untitled.png,image/x-png,*base64bytestring*)" >untitled.png</a>
```

javascript code

```
function download(id,name,contenttype,filebyte)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple download function , pass to it the url , file name you want and the type.

```
 function download(url, filename, mimeType){
        return (fetch(url)
            .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
            .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename, {type:mimeType});})
        );
    }

    download('data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=', 'hello.txt', 'text/plain')
    .then(function(file){
        console.log(file);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`download.js`](http://danml.com/download.html) library. Include this library and Try below code with image mime type:

```
<a href="javascript:download(atob('*base64bytestring*'), 'dlText.txt', 'text/plain');" >untitled.txt</a>
```